# SSO for .net core 3.1 web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, single-sign-on, identityserver4, .net-core-3.1

We would like to achieve SSO(`Google, Microsoft, Twitter, Facebook`) for a `.net core 3.1` `web api` (console api controllers) application. I have gone through few links that achieves this with the help of MVC or angular front end and `IdentityServer4`. Our application is purely an web api. Can some one guide me with sample code or link to achieve this? How does SignInWithGoogle/FB/Twitter/Microsoft button and its click will be handled?

Comment: This question is a little too general. Have you looked at the `identityserver4` samples?

Comment: I did look at http://docs.identityserver.io/en/3.1.0/topics/signin_external_providers.html. but would like to its implementation for web api.